# Capturing errors in a third party cross domain script

Tags: javascript, web, browser, error-handling, cross-domain

I have a script loaded from a 3rd party domain (3p.com) into a webpage (page.com)

The goal is to capture `error` and `unhandledrejection` occurring in the 3p script and ping this back to a server for logging.

Whilst there are event handlers available in the browser for this, it seems they do not allow any meaningful collection of information, from the MDN [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#notes):

```
When an error occurs in a script, loaded from a different origin, the details of the error are not reported to prevent leaking information (see bug 363897).
```

Is there a way to do this? Ideal solution is global and hooks into these events, then allows filtering to only errors from the concerned script. However if would be happy to also wrap the script execution into a try / catch if this would capture all possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set up your server so that requests to that third-party domain get bounced off your server, so that your clients have the ability to programatically examine possible errors that get thrown. For example, instead of serving to your clients

```
<script src="https://3p.com/script.js"></script>
```

serve

```
<script src="https://yoursite.com/get3pscript"></script>
```

where the `get3pscript` route on your site makes a request to `https://3p.com/script.js`, then sends the response to the client, making sure the MIME type is correct. Then the client will be able to do whatever it wants with the script element without cross-domain issues.

Comment: I am sorry this must be due to my wording, I am actually the 3rd party script in this case so would not be able to do this :(